# How do I install python on a windows machine using a cygwin terminal?

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to install python through cygwin on a windows machine in order to make use of a statistical program that can only be implemented using python in a linux environment.

I have run `setup-x86_64.exe` and installed all python related cygwin packages in an attempt to install python, but when I open a terminal and type `python` I just get

```
$ python
-bash: python: command not found
```

which is the same for all python commands I try so clearly the installation has not occurred. However, I have found a path to `Python-2.7.9` which appears to contain the files required to build python from source.

When I run `./configure` it is successful, but when I then input `make` it fails due to:

```
File "build/temp.cygwin-1.7.35-x86_64-2.7/libffi/fficonfig.py", line 33, in   <module>                                                                               
ffi_sources += ffi_platforms['X86_WIN64']
KeyError: 'X86_WIN64'
Makefile:488: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
```

Anyone know why `make` won't work?

The options in `./configure --help` are unfamiliar to me, could any of these options allow for successful installation?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: when using cygwin, just use the "setup.exe" file from cygwin.com and choose the python package from the "devel" list. You really don't need to install it from src!

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, but the only python package in the "devel" list that wasn't already installed was a python-pyrex package that has not helped. I have tried to add so many cygwin packages based on so many web pages that it feels like a big mess now. Do you have a list of every cygwin package required to run python?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin comes with an installer, called `setup.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe`. Just run it and type `python` to the search box. Then let it install it for you.

`python language interpreter` is the basic package you need.

Comment: So should I install every python package available? How would I test whether not it has worked?

Comment: @JackBowyer you should install the toplevel "python" package. And to test that it worked, simpy start Cygwin and type "python".

Comment: When I type "python" I just get `-bash: python: command not found`

Comment: @JackBowyer that either means the installtion did not work or your environment is somehow broken. Do a `ls -l /usr/bin/python` or `ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7`. If both of those return empty, its not your environment, which means probably your Cygwin installation itself is broken - try to remove it completely and then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

So, this question is 3 years old, but this error still happens with most recent versions of Python 2 (tested with `2.7.13` and `2.7.15`)

I was able to get python to build by modifying the following file in the build directory.

```
--- build/temp.cygwin-2.11.1-x86_64-2.7/libffi/fficonfig.py~    2018-11-03 14:51:53.290000000 -0400
+++ build/temp.cygwin-2.11.1-x86_64-2.7/libffi/fficonfig.py     2018-11-03 14:53:41.793000000 -0400
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
     'X86': ['src/x86/ffi.c', 'src/x86/sysv.S', 'src/x86/win32.S'],
     'X86_FREEBSD': ['src/x86/ffi.c', 'src/x86/freebsd.S'],
     'X86_WIN32': ['src/x86/ffi.c', 'src/x86/win32.S'],
+    'X86_WIN64': ['src/x86/ffi.c', 'src/x86/win64.S'],
     'SPARC': ['src/sparc/ffi.c', 'src/sparc/v8.S', 'src/sparc/v9.S'],
     'ALPHA': ['src/alpha/ffi.c', 'src/alpha/osf.S'],
     'IA64': ['src/ia64/ffi.c', 'src/ia64/unix.S'],
```

The source files, in particular `src/x86/win64.S`, are present in the source tree.  For some reason, `./configure` does not seem to be properly adding the option to the dictionary in the `fficonfig.py` file, which causes the KeyError posted in the question.  After making this modification, `make` and `make install` completed successfully and I was able to install an alternate version of python in addition to the normal Cygwin package.

I'm not yet sure why this happens, but I thought I would attempt to provide a solution to the question actually asked rather than just telling the asker to install a pre-compiled version using the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Since building Python from source was said to be a bad idea, I assumed my Cygwin was broken. I attempted to uninstall Cygwin following the instructions on the Cygwin website, but I was unable to remove it due to permission difficulties (I use a university-supplied Windows machine). My last resort was to run the Cygwin installation wizard `setup-x86_64.exe` and uninstall all packages, then run the wizard once more and select the necessary packages again as if starting from new. Miraculously, installing the required packages from scratch solved the problem and I am now running Python through my Cygwin terminal with no errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run Python on Cygwin, you might need to build it from source.

- download the source
- unpack it to the directory you could delete later, eg: `build`
- run Cygwin, type: `cd /path/to/build`
- run `./configure --help` and read the help about the options you'll need
- `./configure #options`
- `make`

Comment: Thanks, I think I have located the path to the source, I ran "./configure" which was fine, but the following "make" failed due to: $ make
/usr/bin/mkdir -p Include
./Parser/asdl_c.py -h Include ./Parser/Python.asdl
/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory
Makefile:649: recipe for target 'Include/Python-ast.h' failed
make: *** [Include/Python-ast.h] Error 127

Comment: I don't understand what "./configure --help" is saying

Comment: Err, it just asks `configure` to show possible arguments you can pass to it.

Comment: @JackBowyer, it says some path doesn't exist, but which one? The message's too badly formatted, you can try adding it to your question.

Comment: It's in the question now, after "Any ideas?". Thanks.

Comment: "If you want to run Python on Cygwin, you might need to build it from source" - that's complete BS. Cygwin comes with its own python packages, they just need to be installed. [Here](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fpython%2Fpython-2.7.8-1&grep=python) is the latest Cygwin python2 package. [Here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o/wiki/Installing-Python-inside-Cygwin) is a random google result which describes how to install python in cygwin. Building from source is a very, very bad idea unless it is absolutely needed, as it can easily go wrong and requires tons of dependencies.